# Hide Time Portion from ASP.NET MVC View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this code:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString =  "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]
public DateTime EstimatedResolveDate { get; set; }
```

Its in ViewModel. When the ViewModel is displayed on the page, I would like for the time portion to be hidden. Problem is the code doesn't do this and Im not sure why?

Comment: Are you using `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.EstimatedResolveDate)` in your view?

Comment: how you render this in your view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC DisplayFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001756/asp-net-mvc-displayformat)

Comment: Like this <td>@item.EstimatedResolveDate</td>

Comment: If you're not using the Html helpers, data annotations are ignored

Comment: Here is a fiddle showing how to use DisplayFor: http://dotnetfiddle.net/8VWHpL

Comment: And also change this "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}" to "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"

Comment: Its being passed through the ViewBag. How do I use @Html helpers for this purpose

Comment: like this: `@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.EstimatedResolveDate)` or  `@Html.DisplayFor(m => (DateTime)ViewBag.EstimatedResolveDate)`