# How can I display numbers in the view to have spaces as thousands separator?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a property for currency:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
public long Budget { get; set; }
```

It is displayed in my view like this:

```
@Model.Budget
```

How can I display the numbers like this: "10 000 000 000"?

I have tried some different data format strings: `{0:# #}`, `{0:#,#}` and `{0:N0}`, but the numbers are not affected - it just displays as "10000000000".

**Solution**

The problem was this:

```
@Model.Budget
```

It has to be this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Budget)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.Net MVC DisplayFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001756/asp-net-mvc-displayformat) DisplayFormat is not affecting `@Model.Budget` you can use .ToString("Format") in your view.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts Absolutely!